# What does psexec -s do?

Tags: psexec

I want to run some commands on the remote machine. I am using `psexec.exe` in my application, when I try to run some command using `-h` and `-s` arguments as mentioned in the below command.

```
C:\psexec.exe -accepteula \\IPAddress -h -u "Username" -p pwd -s netstat -bno
```

When we provide a valid username and password it works with provided credentials, but when we provide username and password which is not valid it picks up `-s` and works I have done some research on **-s** it says **-s = Run the remote process in the System account**.

What exactly `-s` command do, when running above mentioned command on a particular remote machine with the arguments like `-h` and `-s` together is user passed Username and Password will be preferred over `-s`?

Answer (score 1):

With `-s` your command is executed with the **System** account. The **System** account is a special Windows account used to run core Windows services (more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/120929/how-the-system-account-is-used-in-windows)); this account also has special privileges, for example access to registry keys that is denied to all other accounts.

As you can read in the linked docs:

> This account does not have a password

so you don't have to specify a password when using the **System** account.

This is how PsExec works:

- When you add the `-s` parameter the command is executed with the **System** account, so `-u` and `-p` parameters are ignored.
- If you specify `-h` (but not `-s`), then account and password (`-u` and `-p`) are used to connect and execute the process with the account's elevated token (if available), so *they must be correct*.
- If you specify `-h` together with `-s` then account and password (`-u` and `-p`) will NOT be used to connect, since the command will be executed with the **System** account anyway.

You can double check this behavior launching a program on a remote server and looking at the task manager of the remote machine: you will see that, using `-s`, the program will run under the **System** account, otherwise it will run under the user specified with `-u`.

For example if you run notepad with this command:

```
psexec \\remote_server -u domain\user -p correct_password -d -i -s cmd /c notepad.exe
```

or with this command:

```
psexec \\remote_server -u domain\user -p correct_password -d -i -s -h cmd /c notepad.exe
```

or with this command:

```
psexec \\remote_server -u domain\user -p wrong_password -d -i -s -h cmd /c notepad.exe
```

in all these three cases notepad is executed under the **System** account:

[image]